# How to fix ''Follow.s_id' is not a foreign key to 'Users'." in this model

Tags: django-models

I am new to Django framework, I am trying to build the following system which contains a user who follows multiple stocks and the stocks are followed by multiple people, I'm trying to create a composite key using an intermediate class, but I'm having this error.

```py
class Stock(models.Model):
    symbol = models.CharField(max_length=12, primary_key=True,default="")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    top_rank = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    price = models.FloatField()
    change = models.FloatField(null=True)
    change_percent = models.FloatField()
    market_cap = models.FloatField(null=True)
    primary_exchange = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=32) # NASDAQ
    followers = models.ManyToManyField('myapp.Users',through='Follow',through_fields=('u_id','s_id'))


class Users(models.Model):
    user_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True,default="")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=12)

class Follow(models.Model):
    u_id=models.ForeignKey('Users',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    s_id=models.ForeignKey('Stock',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

```
myapp.Stock.followers: (fields.E339) 'Follow.s_id' is not a foreign key to 'Users'.
        HINT: Did you mean one of the following foreign keys to 'Users': u_id?
myapp.Stock.followers: (fields.E339) 'Follow.u_id' is not a foreign key to 'Stock'.
        HINT: Did you mean one of the following foreign keys to 'Stock': s_id?
```

Comment: The `through_fields` should be `('u_id', 's_id')`, but usually one does not add a suffix anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order of the [**`through_fields`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through_fields) is incorrect. As specified in the documentation:

> `through_fields` accepts a 2-tuple `('field1', 'field2')`, where `field1` is the name of the foreign key to the **model the `ManyToManyField` is defined on** (...), and `field2` the name of the foreign key to the **target model** (...).

So that means the first item of the `through_fields` should be `'s_id'` here, since that refers to the `Stock` model, the model where you defined the `ManyToManyField`, and the second item should be `'u_id'`:

```
class Stock(models.Model):
    # …
    followers = models.ManyToManyField(
        'myapp.Users',
        through='Follow',
        through_fields=('s_id','u_id')
    )
```

That being said, you here do not need to define the `through_fields` here, since your `Follow` model contains *exactly* two `ForeignKey`s that point to different models. In fact you do not need to  define a `through=...` model either, since it does not contain any extra fields.

Note that usually a `ForeignKey` does *not* contain an `_id` suffix, since Django will automatically add an extra field with the `_id` suffix that contains the primary key of the referenced value.

Therefore it might make more sense, to just define the models as:

```
class Stock(models.Model):
    symbol = models.CharField(max_length=12, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    top_rank = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    price = models.FloatField()
    change = models.FloatField(null=True)
    change_percent = models.FloatField()
    market_cap = models.FloatField(null=True)
    primary_exchange = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=32) # NASDAQ
    followers = models.ManyToManyField('myapp.User')


class User(models.Model):
    user_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=12)
```

Note that models usually have a *singular* name, so `User`, instead of <s>`Users`</s>.